# Error 'Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, class

I am new to learning ES6 and I have the following code below. The code runs and does the correct output but in my console I receive a "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". Could someone please tell me why it is giving this error.

```
class Vehicle {
    constructor(color = 'blue', wheels = 4, horn = 'beep beep') {
        this.color = color;
        this.wheels = wheels;
        this.horn = horn;
    }

    honkHorn() {
        console.log(this.horn);
    }
}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle{
    constructor(color, wheels, horn){
        super(color, wheels, horn);
        this.wheels = 2;
        this.horn = 'honk honk';
      
    }
 
}

const myVehicle = new Vehicle();
myVehicle.honkHorn(); // beep beep
const myBike = new Bicycle();
myBike.honkHorn(); // honk honk
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? The error looks as if you are calling `.name` property from a variable, yet I don't see a `.name` in your code

Comment: This was the whole code.

Comment: You may need to post the rest of the page or your method of serving/client software. I tested your code. Ran fine, no errors. Just beep beep/honk honk and a complaint because I didn't bother with character encoding for the html document. IE: the only error I had was UNrelated to your code.